# How to create a grid according to the orientation of a polygon

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

How can I make a grid according to the orientation of a polygon with some interval, where the polygon has always 4 point data with different orientation, for example my polygon looks like this :

```
x1 = np.array([50,0,150,200,50])
y1 = np.array([10,-50,-60,0,10])
```

and I want to make grid like this :

[image]

Comment: And what do you want to get in return, from `x1` and `y1`?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher x1 and y1 is the point of polygon, and i want to make grid according to this points (it looks like the image i send)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `LineCollection` of "grid lines" by subdividing the polygon edges into equidistant parts as shown below. In the function `grid`, `nx` and `ny` are the number of lines to create per dimension of the polygon.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

def grid(x,y, nx, ny, **kwargs):
    def verts(a,b,c,d,n):
        l1x = np.linspace(x[a],x[b], n)
        l1y = np.linspace(y[a],y[b], n)
        l2x = np.linspace(x[d],x[c], n)
        l2y = np.linspace(y[d],y[c], n)
        return np.stack((np.c_[l1x, l2x], np.c_[l1y, l2y]), axis=-1)
    v = np.concatenate((verts(0,1,2,3,ny), verts(1,2,3,4,nx)), axis=0)
    return LineCollection(v, **kwargs)

x1 = np.array([50,0,150,200,50])
y1 = np.array([10,-50,-60,0,10])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_collection(grid(x1,y1,5,6, color="gray"))

rect=Polygon(np.c_[x1,y1], edgecolor="C0", linewidth=2, facecolor="none", zorder=3)
ax.add_patch(rect)

ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, this method is very helpful for visualizing my data

Answer (score 1):

You can use a interpolate function for each coordinate:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

x = np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.float)
y = np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.float)
```

Now we need to create the interpolate function so that on the small unit square (0,1)x(0,1), we get the result we want.

```
zx = np.array([[0, 150],[50, 200]])
fx = interp2d(x, y, zx)

fx(0.5, 0.5)
```

Do the same for `zy` to get the `y` coordinate inside your polygon.

Comment: nice solution for my case, i can get all the point of the grid for the next calculation. thanks, your answer very helpful